# Issue with order of plugin execution in maven builds

Tags: java, maven

I am working with a maven project and I have a local dependency (i.e a jar residing in my local file system). In order to include that dependency as part of fat jar of my project, I have to install it locally in my .m2 repository and then use it as a normal dependency in pom.xml file.

I want to automate this process of installing the jar locally. So, I tried using the

> maven-install-plugin:install-file

goal at **validation** phase. Based on this configuration, I expect that this plugin to execute before anything and when it comes to compile/package, the dependency is available locally to pick up from.

But with the above configuration, **mvn validate** and **mvn compile** commands are running successfully individually. But when it comes to **mvn package**, the build is trying to find the dependency in the central maven repo and throwing an error saying that it isn't found in the central repository.

Does **mvn package** run some additional checks before **validate** phase which the **mvn compile** doesn't? It seems like some checks are running before the plugins at **validate** phase are executed, that too only in the case of **mvn package**.

Is there a way to execute the above mentioned goal as a starting point of execution for any maven command?

Comment: First question coming up here: `I have to install it locally in my .m2 repository ` why?   Do you use a repository manager? Only on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup does not work.

Maven picks up dependencies before **any phase runs**. So installing a dependency during the build will not allow you to use the dependency.